# How to send GET requests via python over different IPs?

Tags: python, https, proxy, python-requests

I am currently trying to gather data from an exchange for deep learning. The issue is I need the data with a high resolution (second intervals), therefore I am creating a lot of GET requests for each currency. But I reach fast the limits of the API really.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to route the GET request over a public proxy server to claim to have a different IP-address to make as many requests as possible with a Raspberry PI.

Comment: You want us to help you circumvent the rate limit of an API?

Comment: I need to, else I won't be able to get the needed data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just an more detailed version of the verified answers**

> How To Download?

```
pip3 install proxy-requests
```

> Example for Basic GET Request

```
from proxy_requests import ProxyRequests
r = ProxyRequests("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
r.get()
```

> Example for GET Request with Headers

```
from proxy_requests import ProxyRequests
h = {'User-Agent': 'NCSA Mosaic/3.0 (Windows 95)'}                                                             
r = ProxyRequests('url here')                                                                                  
r.set_headers(h)                                                                                               
r.get_with_headers()
```

> Example for POST Request

```
from proxy_requests import ProxyRequests
r = ProxyRequests('url here')                                                                                  
r.post({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
```

> Example for POST Request with Headers

```
r = ProxyRequests('url here')
r.set_headers({'name': 'rootVIII', 'secret_message': '7Yufs9KIfj33d'})
r.post_with_headers({'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'})
```

> Example for Request with Authentication

```
r = ProxyRequestsBasicAuth('url here', 'username', 'password')
r.get()
```

By The way, all these thing are already mentioned on the [Github repository](https://github.com/rootVIII/proxy_requests/).

Answer (score 5):

If you need to make a GET with different proxies/IP addresses...

Try proxy-requests. I am not sure if that's what you are asking, but it seems like maybe you reached your request limit to a your API endpoint. Some organizations limit the number of requests allowed from certain IP addresses.

Here's an example GET using python proxy requests so that your IP will be different:

```
pip3 install proxy-requests
```

```
from proxy_requests.proxy_requests import ProxyRequests
r = ProxyRequests("https://api.ipify.org")
r.get()
```

[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/proxy-requests/)

[github](https://github.com/rootVIII/proxy_requests)

The module seems to use scraped proxies to make the request. I just tried quickly and it worked

Comment: how to provide headers

Comment: how to use it for post request ?

Comment: Pyd Here is how to provide headers: r.set_headers({'User-Agent': 'NCSA Mosaic/3.0 (Windows 95)'})   r.get_with_headers()